# Is it better to use Open mHealth or FHIR for fitness data?

Tags: hl7-fhir

As http://www.healthintersections.com.au/?p=2487 claims, it is possible to model fitness data with FHIR by coding it in Observation resource. Also, Open mHealth is a standard specially designed for mobile health data, which usually include wellness and fitness data. What are their strengths and weaknesses in comparison with each other?

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be possible to map between the two with no data loss. So no need to be too stressed about your decision.

Second, HL7 is an ANSI-accredited standards development organization. You can have a high level of confidence that FHIR is a safe and well-designed way to be storing and/or representing this information. I work at Redox - [this is how we would integrate fitness data](https://developer.redoxengine.com/data-models/Flowsheet.html). Our goal at Redox, which I assume is the goal of an organization like mHealth is to offer a slightly more approachable version of something HL7 makes.

At the end of the day, it's worth investing your time into learning the *why* behind the FHIR design decisions. For example, `coding` is always an array in FHIR, but the [code system in Open mHealth](http://www.openmhealth.org/documentation/#/schema-docs/schema-library/schemas/omh_sleep-duration) is implicit, it doesn't show up anywhere in the data. That's a huge problem if you're trying to integrate with software that doesn't support the one SNOMED code that Open mHealth has chosen.